# Python, Selenium. How to find element by style or by xpath number?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, styles

```
<html>
 <body>
  <pre style="example" xpath="1">
   "amount": 12{
   "value" : 3
    },
  </pre>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is whats given. How am I gonna locate value?

I was thinking about something like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//style='example'")
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yeah, you can use the XPath to find, alternatively, you can use find_element_by_tag_name

Comment: I‘m pretty new to it. Isn’t this command for the attribute "name" or something? And how I‘m gonna use this? find_element_by_tag_name(”xpath=’1’”)? And thx for the response!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the whole xpath in such situation:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/pre[1]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also relative path:

```
//pre[@style='example']
```

Style is an attribute in your case, not a tag name like "pre" this is why you need to access it with @.